# Breakeven Bet: Expected Value and Simulation

Tags: probability, python, expected-value

Here is the problem:

- A bet is known to have a win rate of 25%.
- Upon winning, the bet pays $100.
- Player can choose the cost of the bet.

My understanding is that the breakeven bet size would be 25% times \$100 = $25, equal to the expected value of each bet.

However, I simulated this game with a short Python script:

[image: 100M trials of simple betting game]

The simulation results in a profit, even after 100 million trials. It seems to always result in a profit, I've ran the simulation many times. It appears that ~$33 is closer to the actual breakeven bet size (not shown, I just manually adjusted the bet size higher until the resulting profit converged to about zero).

What am I missing here? Am I calculating the breakeven bet size wrong or is there something wrong with the simulation?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It can help to make the code look as much like the problem description as possible.  At the head of the loop, then, subtract the cost of the bet from `total_value` (you will want to create a constant `cost_of_bet = 25` to do this clearly) to model the cost of the bet. Upon success, add `win_value` to `total_value` to model the gain from winning.  You don't have to do anything when success does not occur!  BTW, why do you use`np.random.normal`? That's obscure and inefficient compared to `np.random.ranf`.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the useful feedback.  I don't have a really good reason for using `np.random.normal`. I found it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) and thought it made sense to specify the distribution from which the randoms were being created ([I compared the distributions here](https://github.com/def-mycroft/shared-ipynb/blob/master/Breakeven%20Bet%20-%20Expected%20Value%20and%20Simulation.ipynb))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your simulation is wrong.  If the cost of placing the bet is 25, and the bet pays out 100 when you win, then the *net* payout is 75.  Right now, you are only charging the player the cost of placing the bet when he/she loses, but not when he/she wins.

Comment: That was exactly the problem - [here is the updated simulation](https://github.com/def-mycroft/shared-ipynb/blob/master/Breakeven%20Bet%20-%20Expected%20Value%20and%20Simulation.ipynb)